# Как "заморозить" n-элементов на странице из массива?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть список дивов, которые являются визуализацией массива из рандломных чисел. Как при клике пользователя заморозить те элементы по которым кликнул пользователь и заменить оставшиеся, при этом сохранить их позицию на экране.

Comment: а вообще где ваш код, и что у вас не получается?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очевидно, необходимо пометить элементы тем или иным способом. Например, добавить класс или атрибут, сохранить их куда-либо и т.п.
В данном примере элементы отмечаются классом `.freeze`.

```js
// функция генерации случайного целого
function getRandomInt(maxValue){
   return Math.floor(Math.random() * maxValue);
}

// генерация div-ов при запуске
$(function(){
   var n = getRandomInt(20);
   while(n--){
      var value = getRandomInt(100);
      $('<div class="num"></div>').text(value).appendTo("#numbers");
   }
});

// клик на диве, его фиксация, заполнение новых значений
$("#numbers").on('click', '.num:not(.freeze)', function(){
   $(this).addClass("freeze");
   $(".num:not(.freeze)").each(function(idx, v){ 
       $(v).text(getRandomInt(100));
   });
   
});
```

```css
.num {
   float: left;
   width: 40px;
   height: 40px;
   margin: 4px;
   border: 1px solid red;
   text-align: center;
   line-height: 40px;
   cursor: pointer;
}

.freeze {
   border-color: blue;   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="numbers"></div>
```

Comment: Не получалось именно фиксация элемента и заполнение новыми значениями остальных дивов. Код не приложил ибо там много чего не относящегося именно к этой проблеме и только сбивало бы с толку. Но Ваш вариант мне очень помог, спасибо